# VLOOKUP from GoogleSheets doesn't work. The formula is not active

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I do not understand anything. Even the syntax is not as reflected as in the guides. It's like my table doesn't know anything about VLOOKUP at all.

Maybe it's because of the symbols of the Polish language? Although I want to search by Uniqueid and output the name as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your sheet most likely uses [semicolon convention](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/sheets-location/):*

```js
=vlookup(H8;A:B;2;false)
```

Comment: OMG ! Thank you very much. I feel a little ashamed that I didn't think of it myself.
But this is my first experience with GoogleSheets. Thank you again.